# Laravel 5.0 how to add a custom check before registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I am working a Laravel project (Laravel 5.0) and came across a roadblock. Basically what I am trying to do is make it so that only people with a certain email domain (let's say @gmail.com as an example) to register. I have looked through almost all of the files to do with registration and can't seem to find where to add a check.

The code is really simple:

```
if (substr($email,-10,10)!="@gmail.com") { 
    echo "we have an issue here";
}
```

Now, preferably, it wouldn't just echo an error, but rather include it in the list of errors such as when you leave the name field blank.

If you know how to do this, please post some code and the file to put said code in.

Thanks again!

P.S. I am using all of the default authentication built into Laravel 5.0 to do my registration and login.

Comment: Create a custom validator

Comment: @Digitlimit can you please elaborate on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you need to do is create a custom validator
There are several ways to make a custom validator in Laravel but I prefer doing it like so:

1. Firstly create a custom validator class, this will serve as a place where you can register all your custom validators in the future,
   Mine is located in `app\customs` - I created `customs` directory as it doesn't exists.

   ```
   <?php namespace App\Customs;

   use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

   class Validators extends Validator
   {

         public function validateGoodEmail($attribute, $value, $parameters)
         {
            return (substr($value,-10,10)!="@gmail.com"); 
            //return boolen - true or false
         }

   }
   ```

NB: Notice the keyword in the method name`validate` example validateGoodEmail, validateSex etc.

2. **Updated:** Next up, create a ValidatorServiceProvider.php in `app\providers` and do something similar to this:

   ```
   <?php namespace App\Providers;

   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   use Validator;
   use App\Customs\Validators;

   class ValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {

         public function boot()
         {
              Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages){
                   return new Validators($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
              });
         }


         public function register()
         {

         }
   }
   ```
3. Register the newly created service provider in `config/app.php` under providers

   ```
    'App\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider',
   ```
4. To use the validator in default laravel registration process, pop open
   `app\services\Registrar.php` and add this

NB: In Laravel 5.2 checkout `app\http\controllers\auth\AuthController.php`

```
use App\User;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar as RegistrarContract;
use Mail;

class Registrar implements RegistrarContract {

    public function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|good_email|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Updated:**
***For a quick fix, you can skip step 1 - 4 and simply modify `app\services\Registrar.php` like so:***

```
public function validator(array $data)
{
     \Validator::extend('good_email', function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
             return (substr($value,-10,10)!="@gmail.com"); 
      });

      return \Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|good_email|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
 }
```

5. One last thing to do is add `good_email` in `resources\lang\en\validation.php`

   ```
   'unique'               => 'The :attribute has already been tak
   'url'                  => 'The :attribute format is invalid.',

   ......                                                               
   'good_email'       => 'Sorry :attribute must end with "@gmail.com"',   
   ......
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`AuthController@postRegister` perhaps, which comes from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` Trait.

Comment: I've looked at that, but is is very confusing to me. Where do I get the email from? How do I log a custom message that says "Sorry your email must end in "@gmail.com"?

Comment: I have looked at the Request class (\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Request.php) and I have no idea how to extract the email from the functions provided in it. If you know how, please inform me

Comment: Thanks so much! This is perfect (almost), I now know how to get the users email, but what about the custom error part?

Comment: you could redirect with a message and check for that in the view, or withErrors and add your message to it since you are probably checking for `$errors` already.